# Internal gd font () not available use only 1-5

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, php-gd

I am using Laravel framework and image/intervention library for generating images with dynamic data. The code is running perfectly fine on my local machine but as soon as I upload it on aws ubuntu instance it is showing error like Internal gd font() not available. I tried switching to imagick and public_path() but it is still showing the same error. My code is as follows:

I tried switching to imagick and public_path() but it is still showing the same error. My code is as follows:

public function generateIdCard(Request $request){

```
    $user = app('App\Http\Controllers\ApiTokenController')->authenticate($request);
    if($user == null)
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Token Invalid','status'=>0], 200);

    $user = MatchmakerUser::where('id', $user->id)->first();
    if($user){
    $img=Image::make($this->url2.'2.png');
    $filename = 'mmProfilePic_'.$user->id.'.jpg';
    $profilepicurl=$this->url.$filename;
    $img2=Image::make($profilepicurl)->resize(82,82);
    $img->insert($img2,'top-left',22,24);
    $name=$user->first_name.$user->last_name;
    $img->text($name,115, 50, function($font) {
        $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf');
        $font->size(18);
        $font->color('#fff');
        $font->valign('top');
    });
    $designation=$user->matchmaker_type;
    $img->text($designation,115, 73, function($font) {
        $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
        $font->size(10);
        $font->color('#fff');
        $font->valign('top');
    });
    $phone=$user->phone_number;
    $img->text($phone,31, 129, function($font) {
        $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
        $font->size(10);
        $font->color('#4e4e4e');
        $font->valign('top'); 
    });
    $location=$user->location;
    $img->text($location,33, 148, function($font) {
        $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
        $font->size(10);
        $font->color('#4e4e4e');
        $font->valign('top'); 
    });
    $website="www.hansmatrimony.com/matchmaker";
    $img->text($website,33, 167, function($font) {
        $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
        $font->size(9);
        $font->color('#4e4e4e');
        $font->valign('top'); 
    });
    Storage::disk('s3')->put('static/matchmakerz/id_card/'.'Id_card'.$user->id, file_get_contents($img), 'public');
    IdCard::create([
        'id_card'=>'static/matchmakerz/id_card/'.'Id_card'.$user->id,
        'matchmaker_id'=>$user->id
        ]);
        return response(['matchmaker_id_card'=>$this->url2.'id_card'.$user->id,'name'=>$name,'status'=>1,'message'=>'success'], 200);
    }

    elseif($user == null)
        return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'No User details found'], 200);
    else
        return response()->json(['status' => 0, 'message' => 'Some Error Occurred'], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A year late, but here's to anyone else searching for the answer in 2020 and beyond like me.

I found you have to use `public_path()` to get the correct path to the file. So change this:

```
    $font->file('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf');
```

To this:

```
    $font->file(public_path('../../../fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf'));
```

You may need to double-check that the relative path you are giving is correct. (So check what is output by calling `public_path()` and make sure the file exists.)

Comment: As of L8, ```$font->file(public_path('fonts/RobotoMono.ttf'));``` is working fine.